# How to create a zip file where a file name starts with a dot

Tags: windows, powershell, compress-archive

I have a situation where I am trying to create a zip file from the command line, but I am trying to add a file which starts with a dot.

```
powershell Compress-Archive -Path .\Dist\._test.txt -DestinationPath .\test
```

But this gives an error `Could not find item Dist\._test.txt`

How can I get this powershell command to include files named this way?

Comment: Quote and use `-LiteralPath`

Comment: @LotPings Don't you need a full path to use `-LiteralPath`? Do they need to do `-LiteralPath $(resolve-path .\Dist\._test.txt).Path`?

Comment: @TheMadTechnician I did test with a file in current folder and that worked. `Compress-Archive -Destin .\test.zip -Literalpath ".lnk"`

Comment: @TheMadTechnician: `-LiteralPath` just means that that no wildcard resolution is applied to the argument, but it can still be a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you try like this, i had test the same and its working fine

```
powershell Compress-Archive -Path "C:\location\.test.png" -DestinationPath "C:\location\destination"
```

Answer (score 0):

Explorer was set to show hidden items. For some reason it wasn't giving a visual indicator that this was a hidden file. I removed the checkbox for "Hidden" and it worked fine.